# Simple CTE recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am sorry to bother with such a simple question, but I decided to learn CTE recursive queries and I am unable to get my query work even after scoping many sources and threads. So I am humbly asking for pointing out my mistake(s).

Here is a part of table I am querying:

```
ID        ContainerInstanceID  ItemID      ContentContainerInstanceID
--------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------------
73        40                   NULL        41        
69        40                   23885       NULL
68        40                   29683       NULL
67        40                   29686       NULL
72        41                   27392       NULL
71        41                   29235       NULL
70        41                   29213       NULL
```

I assembled this simple CTE query:

```
;WITH ContainerContent_CTE(InstanceID,ItemID,ContentContainerInstanceID) AS
 (
  -- ROOT set accordig to input parameter
  SELECT ContainerInstanceID,SCA.ItemID,SCA.ContentContainerInstanceID 
  FROM StockContainerAssignments as SCA 
  WHERE SCA.ContainerInstanceID = 40  -- input parameter

  UNION ALL

  -- recursive data
  SELECT ContainerInstanceID,SCA2.ItemID,SCA2.ContentContainerInstanceID 
  FROM ContainerContent_CTE AS CC
  JOIN StockContainerAssignments as SCA2 on CC.InstanceID = SCA2.ContentContainerInstanceID
  )
SELECT * FROM ContainerContent_CTE;
```

What I am trying to do is to take a top-level container, in this example it has ID = 40, which is my input parameter. Then, I try to connect other levels by linking ContainerInstanceID with ContentContainerInstanceID. In my example it is not null ar row ID = 73. This should add another 3 rows to my result set (so it should look similar to the example data I presented above), but I still get only top level rows:

```
InstanceID   ItemID  ContentContainerInstanceID
-----------  ----------- --------------------------
40           29686       NULL
40           29683       NULL
40           23885       NULL
40           NULL        41
```

I appreciate hints to help me stumble over this subject.

Comment: Your FROM and JOIN tables are backwards in the second half.

Comment: Which version are you using? have you tried a cross join instead of join?

Comment: @Sean, I tried both (I saw both examples in online resources), actually this is the 2nd version. It has no effect on the result set whatsoever...

Comment: And since you are just starting with ctes, they don't actually start with a semi-colon. The requirement for a cte is that the previous statement MUST be terminated with one. As such many examples show them like this. It is just a pet peeve of mine. The semi-colon is a statement terminator, not a statement beginninator. :)

Comment: @Sean Lange: Yep, I am in habbit of using terminators, I used CTEs in past, but in most case adopted solution from others. That's where I got used to "beginnator" in this case :-)

Comment: @Sean Lange whilst you are technically correct, there is actually no harm in adding extra semi-colons. For me, it is better to start the CTE with a semi-colon, just in case the previous statement hasn't been terminated correctly. Otherwise the effects are somewhat annoying. Aaron Bertrand explains why he does it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/why-should-a-cte-start-with-a-semi-colon). But technically you are correct, it isn't necessary, but personally, I think it's good practice.

Comment: @DimUser, this was not the case however your comment lead me to a solution. I had a missmatch in the ON clause, connecting the parent and child with the oposite pairs of IDs.

Comment: @DimUser as I said it is a pet peeve, there is no harm in it of course. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just had a few little things out of place. This should work for you.

```
with ContainerContent_CTE as
(
    select SCA.ContainerInstanceID
        ,SCA.ItemID
        ,SCA.ContentContainerInstanceID 
    FROM StockContainerAssignments as SCA 
    WHERE SCA.ContainerInstanceID = 40  -- input parameter

    UNION ALL 

    select SCA.ContainerInstanceID
        ,SCA.ItemID
        ,SCA.ContentContainerInstanceID 
    FROM StockContainerAssignments as SCA
    inner join ContainerContent_CTE cte on cte.ContentContainerInstanceID = SCA.ContainerInstanceID
)

select *
from ContainerContent_CTE
```

Comment: Yes, it works indeed. I am marking it as the answer, because you kept the naming convention for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
declare @t table (id int, instance int, container int);
insert into @t values 
               (73, 40, 41)       
             , (69, 40, NULL)
             , (68, 40, NULL)
             , (67, 40, NULL)
             , (72, 41, NULL)
             , (71, 41, NULL)
             , (70, 41, NULL);
select * from @t;
with cte as 
( select t.id, t.instance, t.container
  from @t t
  where t.instance = 40 
  union all 
  select t.id, t.instance, t.container
  from cte 
  join @t t 
    on t.instance = cte.container
)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: Tested, this works too. I can only mark one answer though, so I only up-voted this answer. Thank you @Paparazzi.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 I am fine with not getting the check mark.  The original naming is more clear to you but it would not be more clear to others looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

As expected, a dumb little mistake got in a way - in the ON clause, I was connecting the parent and child with the oposite pairs of IDs. Since I'm only learning CTE, it was hard to see for me. Here it's fixed (for referrence):

```
;WITH ContainerContent_CTE(InstanceID,temID,ContentContainerInstanceID) AS
 (
  -- ROOT set accordig to input parameter
  SELECT ContainerInstanceID,SCA.ItemID,SCA.ContentContainerInstanceID 
  FROM StockContainerAssignments as SCA 
  WHERE SCA.ContainerInstanceID = 40  -- input parameter

  UNION ALL

  -- recursive data
  SELECT ContainerInstanceID,SCA2.ItemID,SCA2.ContentContainerInstanceID 
  FROM ContainerContent_CTE AS CC
  INNER JOIN StockContainerAssignments as SCA2 on CC.ContentContainerInstanceID = SCA2.ContainerInstanceID)
SELECT * FROM ContainerContent_CTE;
```

Thank you for suggestions.